# Can not do UI work in method finish() of Activity when using Espresso rules?

Tags: android, ui-automation, android-espresso

I'm using Espresso to do UI test for my Android app.

Following the official guide, I used ActivityTestRule to launch the Activity under test. But when test finishes, a crash occurred.

stack trace is

```
android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6247)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.playSoundEffect(ViewRootImpl.java:5222)
at android.view.View.playSoundEffect(View.java:17876)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4755)
at com.example.android.activityinstrumentation.ReadExternalFileActivity.finish(ReadExternalFileActivity.java:196)
at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule.finishActivity(ActivityTestRule.java:234)
at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:259)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:59)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:262)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1837)
```

Throw the call stack, I found AndroidJunitRunner tried to call finish() of the Activity from non-UI thread, which caused the crash.

My app Overrides method finish() of the Activity, popping up a dialog to ask user confirm exit or not, which should be executed on UI thread.

Does it mean, I can not do UI work in finish() method of Activity when using Espresso? Or is this a bug of Espresso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not do UI work in finish().

finish() is NOT for this purpose. finish() is what happens after the user says yes to that dialog.

The Activity should be gone from the screen by the time it reaches it. I'm actually a little surprised it took a test-case to see that fail.

Comment: Sadly, it's not written in Android official doc. Look, I misused method finish() for years.

Comment: I would be totally unsurprised if the exact order of events involving calls to finish() was not defined (or even if you could avoid this problem by moving the call to super.finish()  to the end of your method), but I wouldn't recommend relying on it.

Answer (score 0):

You are allowed to do UI work on `finish()`, normally it is just used the close the last dialogs, cursors and so on, you can also do that on `onDestroy`.

Without some code excerpt, I can't say if there is a bug somewhere in your code. My recommendation would be for you to move your confirmation dialog to the `onBackPressed`, just add the dialog and when the user confirms he/she wants to exit make a call to `super.onBackPressed()` otherwise don't do anything.